# is it possible to get the C# class original name to improve the code readablity from obfuscated exe

Tags: c#, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have a windows exe program, I know it was written using C#, when I decrypt the dll(exe) using ILSpy 7.6, the class code look like this:

```
namespace eGTt4d2HADJI3qZvyr
{

 internal class epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y
  {
    internal static ModuleHandle e1gr6SXh7;
    internal static RuntimeTypeHandle e53w34m968awCm9P85taUZe(int token)
    {
        return epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y.e1gr6SXh7.GetRuntimeTypeHandleFromMetadataToken(token);
    }
    internal static RuntimeFieldHandle q3oMVe54wE47w4v68C7s2I(int token)
    {
        return epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y.e1gr6SXh7.GetRuntimeFieldHandleFromMetadataToken(token);
    }
    public epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y()
    {
        <PrivateImplementationDetails>{75896B12-4F98-4FD3-B464-42D866146FAE}.SLV0fFIsptsZtjvFft17();
        base..ctor();
    }
    static epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y()
    {
        // Note: this type is marked as 'beforefieldinit'.
        <PrivateImplementationDetails>{75896B12-4F98-4FD3-B464-42D866146FAE}.SLV0fFIsptsZtjvFft17();
        epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y.e1gr6SXh7 = typeof(epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y).Assembly.GetModules()[0].ModuleHandle;
    }
  }
}
```

I was wonder that is it possilbe to refactor the real name of the code. Because the name of code almost unreadable, no one could understand the meaning from the meanless code name.How can I get the original name? Is it possible to get the real name or improve the readable of the code?

Comment: how you get the name how? you mean by reflection?....and this is just my opinion but you should consider other naming convention.

Comment: Is this decompiled code?

Comment: This looks like you're trying to reverse-engineer obfuscated code... is that the case?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with encryption. Mangling class names like this is actually called obfuscation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is obfuscated code. The only way you will be able to get the original class names is if you have the code before obfuscation. Unless the writer of the code left some holes in it, the only option is to go through the code and spend a lot of time refactoring the code to get rid of the obscurity and try and make some sense out of it, but it would probably be quicker to write your own application that does the same thing.

As an additional note, since the code is obfuscated, the code has the real class names. Even if you were to call a method that returned the class name, this is exactly what you should expect to get.

Answer (score 6):

You have most probably **decompiled** an **obfuscated** exe. The main reason of *obfuscation* is to protect the code. So, you won't be able to get the original class names unless you know how the code is obfuscated (pattern/algorithm) etc. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29).

Comment: Well, you can get them, if you reverse-engineer the obfuscation program, but good luck with that.

Comment: @gunr2171 As difficult as that is, you likely wouldn't even know what obfuscation program was used!

Comment: The source was *.dll file,i use the ILSpy to reflect it.Most of the code was normal,and a small part like this.If any one knows the Arithmatic.Althrough the Reflector can't work normal.

Comment: @Dolphin if this is the only part of the code that was obfuscated like this, then this part is either something the writer did not want you to know, such as a security-sensitive piece of code, or it is generated code.